# Memory Leak using Native C Sinch Client during Calling stage

Tags: android, memory, client, native, sinch

I am developing an app that uses video calls using the Sinch SDK for Android.

Everything works correctly except when a call is made and the remote user takes time to answer. If the remote user answers soon the video call is successful. But when the user takes time to answer, the memory used by native calls shoots up consuming all memory and the app closes. This only happens with video calls, with voice calls work perfectly.

Has something similar happened to someone or has any possible idea why it could be?

Thanks.

**Edited:** I have not managed to find the error that consumed all the memory because it was from the Sinch library (or perhaps the interaction of this with my development device - Moto G3). In the end I opted to change the API and use Agora. Now everything is fine (although this library is less complete than Sinch and you have to implement communication (Signaling)).

Answer (score 0):

To track every memory leak in your app and find out what's causing it you can try out this library [github/square](https://github.com/square/leakcanary)